# Using two jQuery event methods to perform the same set of functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this example, I'm trying to get my if statement using `.css` to work both on `.ready` AND `.resize` but I don't understand how to combine them.

```
var windowsize = $(window).width();

$(window).ready(function() {

  windowsize = $(window).width();

  if (windowsize > 440) {

    $('body').css("background-color", "blue");

  }
  else { 

$('body').css("background-color", "red");  

  }

});
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

```
function resizeMe(){
  var windowsize = $(window).width();

  if (windowsize > 440) {
    $('body').css("background-color", "blue");
  } else { 
    $('body').css("background-color", "red");  
  }
}


$(window).ready(resizeMe)
         .resize(resizeMe);
```

or, thanks to @Palpatim, this way:

```
$(window).on("ready resize", resizeMe);
```

and can simplify the function to ( thanks to @bfontaine ):

```
function resizeMe(){
    $('body').css("background-color", $(window).width() > 440 ? "blue" : "red");
}
```

Comment: Slightly better than "guest271314"'s answer since you're factoring the handler into a standalone function. Now marry that with a single assignment `$(window).on("ready resize", resizeMe);` and you'll really be cooking with gas. :)

Comment: Why not inlining the condition ? `$('body').css("background-color", windowsize > 440 ? "blue" : "red");`

Comment: i didnt dig too deep into the function logic, @bfontaine =) but it may be done this way of course. or even without variable declaration `$('body').css("background-color", $(window).width() > 440 ? "blue" : "red");`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(window).on("load resize", function() {    
  var windowsize = $(window).width();    
  if (windowsize > 440) {    
    $('body').css("background-color", "blue");    
  }
  else {     
    $('body').css("background-color", "red");      
  };    
}).resize();
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/mnk7ovmg/